# Turn numeric text string with powers of ten nomenclator (e+) into float in python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, exponential

I've got a `dataframe` with more than 30000 rows and almost 40 columns exported from a `csv` file.

The most part of it mixes `str` with `int` features.

-integers are `int`

-floats and powers of ten are `str`

It looks like this:

```
Id       A                 B
1        2.5220019e+008    1742087
2        1.7766118e+008    2223964.5
3        3.3750285e+008    2705867.8
4        97782360          2.5220019e+008
```

I've tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, shape

df = pd.read_csv('mycsvfile.csv').astype(float)
```

Which yields the this error message:

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-1.#IND'`

I guess that it has to do about the exponencial nomenclator of powers of ten (e+) that the python libraries isn't able to transform.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: looks like you have the string `-1.#IND` in your csv file. All other `1e+5`, etc would be transformed without errors.

Comment: @QuangHoang Do you know how I could I identify it?

Comment: use `pd.to_numeric(df['column'], errors='coerce')` to replace them by `nan`, then you can filter them.

Comment: @QuangHoang it works!
here's the code I ran: df2 = df.apply(lambda x : pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my conversation with [QuangHoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang) I should apply the function:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['column'], errors='coerce')
```

Since almost the whole `DataFrame` are `str` objects, I ran the following code line:

```
df2 = df.apply(lambda x : pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
```